# Loading php.ini settings for a PHP Swig

Tags: php, swig

I'm working on a PHP extension, created using the Swig library. I've examined [the Swig & PHP documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Php.html) carefully, but I can't seem to figure out how to parse a value out of php.ini the Swig way. To be clear: let's say I have a section in my php.ini like this:

```
[puppies]
puppies.cuteness=17
```

I want to expose a function in my PHP extension to retrieve this value. Something like:

```
int getCuteness(){
     // access puppies.cuteness here, somehow!
}
```

I've found a variety of tutorials on writing PHP extensions that show how to do this, but I know that Swig wants to abstract a lot of this kind of thing away for me (and anyway, the usual methods don't seem to work in the Swig context).

So, how is this done? *Is* there a Swig way, or am I supposed to stick with the conventional technique? Have any of you done it? Thanks much!

Comment: Just want to confirm you talking about the swig at swig.org and not at https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig

Comment: Yes, swig.org. Got any ideas?